# Joomla plugin database mistakes? What is wrong here?

Tags: ajax, plugins, joomla

i've just started learning Jplugin development, so here i made a little voting script. Everything here works fine, but i want conf.php file to be made in joomla framework style. As you see here, 1 and 2 files works perfectly together. I want to use third example instead of second, in which i use simple php code. The last example i tried to do is using joomla framework, but it doesnt work. I have no idea what's wrong with that code. Anyone see could tell where I made a mistake or maybe far away from doing it right ?

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;
?>

<?php
class plgSystemRatingx extends JPlugin

{
   public function onContentBeforeDisplay()
   {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".like").click(function()
{
var id=$(this).attr("id");
var name=$(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&name='+ name;
$("#votebox").slideDown("slow");

$("#flash").fadeIn("slow");

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "conf.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#flash").fadeOut("slow");
$("#content").html(html);
} 
});
});

$(".close").click(function()
{
$("#votebox").slideUp("slow");
});

});
</script>
<body>
<div style="margin:50px">
<a href="#" class="like" id="1" name="up">Like</a> -- <a href="#" class="like" id="1" name="down">Dislike</a>
<div id="votebox">
<span id='close'><a href="#" class="close" title="Close This">X</a></span>
<div style="height:13px">
<div id="flash">Loading........</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
      return true;
   }
}
```

this piece of code works perfectly

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "px";
$mysql_password = "px";
$mysql_database = "jum";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) 
or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");


if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);


mysql_query("update messages set $name=$name+1 where id='$id'");


$result=mysql_query("select up,down from messages where id='$id'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$up_value=$row['up'];
$down_value=$row['down'];
$total=$up_value+$down_value;

$up_per=($up_value*100)/$total;
$down_per=($down_value*100)/$total;
?>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
<b>Ratings for this blog</b> ( <?php echo $total; ?> total)
</div>
<table width="700px">

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $up_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="greebar" style="width:<?php echo $up_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $down_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="redbar" style="width:<?php echo $down_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

</table>

<?php

}
?>
```

and this made in joomla style doesnt work at all

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;
?>
<?php
if(JRequest::getVar('id'))
{

$id = JRequest::getInt('id');
$name = JRequest::getInt('name');

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query2 = $db->getQuery(true);
$queryup = $db->getQuery(true);
$querydown = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->update('messages');
$query->set("message = 1");
$query->where("id = $id");

$query2->select('up,down');
$query2->from('messages');
$query2->where("id = $id");



$queryup->select('up');
$queryup->from('messages');
$queryup->where("id = $id");

$querydown->select('down');
$querydown->from('messages');
$querydown->where("id = $id");


$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query();
$db->setQuery( $query2 );
$db->query();

$db->setQuery( $queryup );
$data0 = $db->query();
$db->setQuery( $querydown );
$data1 = $db->query();


$up_value= $db->insertid($data0);;
$down_value = $db->insertid($data1);

$total=$up_value+$down_value;

$up_per=($up_value*100)/$total;
$down_per=($down_value*100)/$total;

?>

<table width="700px">

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $up_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="greebar" style="width:<?php echo $up_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="30px"></td>
<td width="60px"><?php echo $down_value; ?></td>
<td width="600px"><div id="redbar" style="width:<?php echo $down_per; ?>%"></div></td>
</tr>

</table>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
$query->where('id = ' . $db->qn($id));

etc

Comment: I forget to mention that, then i use 3rd example, the #content div is not showed, while with php example the content is shown. So problem might somewhere else, even if db is wrong.

Comment: Ok I found out that is wrong. I removed all database thing and left only if($_post) thing in joomla and php files. The first the one wrote in php works and one with joomla not, i think because of defined(_JEXEC). I think this piece of ajax code must be changed somehow or used a different way to get conf.php file. Anyone could tell how to do that ?
the ajax code:
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "conf.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{

Comment: Well the db stuff won't work since you are treating $id as a string and not a variable name so it's good you took it out.  How are you determining it works or not?